# CakePHP controller function with parameters doesn't show javascript

Tags: javascript, cakephp, parameters, controller

When I'm using controller function with parameters the rendered view just seems to forget every included .js files.

```
public function view($id = null) {
    if(!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

    $post = $this->Post->findById($id);

    if(!$post) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }
    $this->set('post', $post);
}
```

If I take parameters away and put variable '$id = 1' on function the view with postID 1 renders okay in 'posts/view'.

I included javascript files to default.ctp in traditional way:

```
echo "script type='text/javascript' SRC='../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>";);
```

(it includes '<' but this text editor won't me type it for safety reasons I guess)

I don't have knowledge about 'js helpers' of cakePHP. Can't I use javascript in traditional way?

Site renders okay in every other view (e.g. posts/add) and .js files are included in source code of 'posts/view/1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem

You're using relative paths to the javascript;

```
<script src='../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
```

In this url, `../` means '1 directory up from the current location`, so when you're currently visiting this URL;

```
http://mysite.com/home/
```

Then your browser will correctly try to load the script from;

```
http://mysite.com/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
```

***However,*** if you're visiting this url;

```
http://mysite.com/home/and/some/more/
```

Then the browser will look for the JavaScript here:

```
http://mysite.com/home/and/some/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
```

#### How to fix the problem

1. Use absolute paths for all 'assets' (CSS, JavaScript, Images);
   `src='/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'`
2. Output the script-tags using CakePHP Helpers (after all, that's what they are meant for: to *simplify* your work :), e.g. `echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.9.1.min');`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now that seems pretty obvious